# What kinds of attack can a bridge carry out?

Tags: anonymity, bridge, deanonymization, attacks

I have been recently doing some research on anonymity implications of using a bridge, and wrote [a tool](https://github.com/nametoolong/oregano) (not very well written though) for setting up a malicious bridge node. However, I am not clear about the attack power that such a bridge has.

Questions:

Does a bridge have any extra attack power other than being the guard-and-dirguard node?

Are there other uncanny attacks that a malicious bridge can perform?

What if something like GFW launches massive MITM attack against bridge connections (since the fingerprint in bridge lines doesn't always come in handy and is often dropped)?